# Pig: Counting the occurence of a grouped column

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In this [raw data](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s308/sh/e65a4196-3427-4098-bf1d-474787b475af/f47b08f839723a4bfe01e9b0e6fd8a60) we have info of baseball players, the schema is:

```
name:chararray, team:chararray, position:bag{t:(p:chararray)}, bat:map[]
```

Using the following script we are able to list out players and the different positions they have played. How do we get a count of how many players have played a particular position?
E.G. How many players were in the 'Designated_hitter' position?

A single position can't appear multiple times in `position` bag for a player.

Pig Script and output for the sample data is listed below.

```
--pig script
players = load 'baseball' as (name:chararray, team:chararray,position:bag{t:(p:chararray)}, bat:map[]);
pos     = foreach players generate name, flatten(position) as position;
groupbyposition = group pos by position;dump groupbyposition;

--dump groupbyposition (output of one position i.e Designated_hitter)
(Designated_hitter,{(Michael Young,Designated_hitter)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you've already done all of the 'grunt' (Ha!, Pig joke) work.  All there it left to do is use [`COUNT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#count) on the output of the `GROUP BY`. Something like:

```
groupbyposition = group pos by position ;
pos_count = FOREACH groupbyposition GENERATE group AS position, COUNT(pos) ;
```

---

<strike>**Note:** Using UDFs you may be able to get a more efficient solution.</strike> If you care about counting a certain few fields then it should be more efficient to filter the `postion` bag before hand (This is why I said UDF, I forgot you could just use a nested `FILTER`).  For example:

```
pos = FOREACH players {
              -- you can also add the DISTINCT that alexeipab points out here
              -- make sure to change postion in the FILTER to dist!
              -- dist = DISTINCT position ;
              filt = FILTER postion BY p MATCHES 'Designated_hitter|etc.' ;
      GENERATE name, FLATTEN(filt) ;
}
```

If none of the positions you want appear in `postion` then it will create an empty bag.  When empty bags are `FLATTEN`ed the row is discarded. This means you'll be `FLATTEN`ing bags of N or less elements (where N is the number of fields you want) instead of 7-15 (didn't really look at the data that closely), and the `GROUP` will be on significantly less data.

**Notes:** I'm not sure if this will be significantly faster (if at all). Also, using a UDF to preform the nested `FILTER` may be faster.

Comment: Could you provide the reasons for UDF being more efficient in this particular case?

Comment: @alexeipab As I hinted at on my comment on your answer I assumed that the positions could not appear multiple times.  That they are just a Boolean, 'has this player ever played this position?'  Assuming this you don't need the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks the above code worked, its correctly listing the number of players who played in a particular position.

Comment: @SwiftGuy Can a postion appear in the position bag multiple times? If it can then alexeipab's answer is correct (minus the current syntax error).

Comment: @mr2ert position does not appear multiple times in position bag.

Comment: @alexeipab What I had in my head wasn't really a UDF after all. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested DISTINCT to get the list of players and than count it.

```
players = load 'baseball' as (name:chararray, team:chararray,position:bag{t:(p:chararray)}, bat:map[]);
pos     = foreach players generate name, flatten(position) as position;
groupbyposition = group pos by position;
pos_count = foreach groupbyposition generate {
     players = DISTINCT name;
     generate group, COUNT(players) as num, pos;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `foreach groupbyposition generate :` be `foreach groupbyposition {`? Also, why use `DISTINCT` here?  A single name can only appear twice in the output of the `GROUP BY` if the player had the same position listed multiple times (which is something that I'd assume wouldn't happen).

Comment: Thanks for : it was a typo. BAGs allow duplicates and we do not know how the bag with positions was created.

Comment: After correcting the foreach typo, the above code was throwing the following error: ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<file /baseball-flatten-groupby.pig, line 6, column 27> Invalid scalar projection: players : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Comment: Try "players = DISTINCT pos.name;"